# Splite URI with regex

Tags: c#, uri, regex-group

I am new in Regex.
I want to splite my host URI like this:xxxPermanentWordChangeWord.myname.city.year.age
i wnat to get: xxx and myname with one pattern regex

i tried this

```
var pattern = " (?=(?<p0>(.*)PermanentWord))?(?=(?<p1>i dont know what to write here in order to get myname))?";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According you question and sample there is what you want.

The idea is:

1. Get the string before **PermanentWordChangeWord.**.
   The rule for this is `(.*)PermanentWordChangeWord\.`
2. Get the value after **PermanentWordChangeWord.** but before **.(dot)**.
   The rule for this is `([^\..]*)` this mean match all but without **.(dot)**

```
var text = "xxxPermanentWordChangeWord.myname.city.year.age";
var pattern = @"(.*)PermanentWordChangeWord\.([^\..]*)";
Regex reg = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = reg.Match(text);

var output = string.Empty;
if (match.Success)
{
    var group0 = match.Groups[0].Value; // This value is: xxxPermanentWordChangeWord.myname.city.year.age
    var group1 = match.Groups[1].Value; //This value is:  xxx
    var group2 = match.Groups[2].Value; //This value is: myname

    output = group1 + group2;
}
```